# How to do a javascript while/do loop INSIDE of a jQuery .html function

Tags: jquery, json, while-loop, do-while

I'm working on a "find name" page - The user inputs one or more letters, the letters are passed to the server via ajax, the server queries a db and the db returns a json array (I learned how to make that yesterday) of names that contain the letters, and I post the list in a div.

Example: User puts in "wa" and "George Washington" is returned (all last names with "wa").

The server side PHP code works great - I've tested it alone and it returns all the right names in the right json format.

The client side works fine, BUT! I used a "brute force" technique just to see if I could put an array in a div by using the jQuery ().html() command (the only command I could get to work - I tried .val, .data and a bunch of other methods for putting the array in a div.).

Here is the code for putting the json array into the div. Yes, correct, it's ugly - but it works as long as the size of the array is >=15 (the number of lines in my "html" - otherwise NOTHING is posted in the div).

```
$.ajax({//------------------------start of ajax---------------------------------->
  type: "POST",
  url: "findpatientbackend.php",
  data: {letterslastname: lastname},
  dataType : 'json',
  success: function(result) {$("#div1").html(
    "----" + result[0].localid + "--------------" + result[0].lastname + "-------------" + result[0].firstname + "<br>" +
    "----" + result[1].localid + "--------------" + result[1].lastname + "-------------" + result[1].firstname + "<br>" +
    "----" + result[2].localid + "--------------" + result[2].lastname + "-------------" + result[2].firstname + "<br>" +
    "----" + result[3].localid + "--------------" + result[3].lastname + "-------------" + result[3].firstname + "<br>" +
    "----" + result[4].localid + "--------------" + result[4].lastname + "-------------" + result[4].firstname + "<br>" +
    "----" + result[5].localid + "--------------" + result[5].lastname + "-------------" + result[5].firstname + "<br>" +
    "----" + result[6].localid + "--------------" + result[6].lastname + "-------------" + result[6].firstname + "<br>" +
    "----" + result[7].localid + "--------------" + result[7].lastname + "-------------" + result[7].firstname + "<br>" +
    "----" + result[8].localid + "--------------" + result[8].lastname + "-------------" + result[8].firstname + "<br>" +
    "----" + result[9].localid + "--------------" + result[9].lastname + "-------------" + result[9].firstname + "<br>" +
    "----" + result[10].localid + "--------------" + result[10].lastname + "-------------" + result[10].firstname + "<br>" +
    "----" + result[11].localid + "--------------" + result[11].lastname + "-------------" + result[11].firstname + "<br>" +            
    "----" + result[12].localid + "--------------" + result[12].lastname + "-------------" + result[12].firstname + "<br>" +    
    "----" + result[13].localid + "--------------" + result[13].lastname + "-------------" + result[13].firstname + "<br>" +    
    "----" + result[14].localid + "--------------" + result[14].lastname + "-------------" + result[14].firstname   
)},
  error : function() { alert("error on return"); }
});
```

So, now to my question.
Given this scenario - parsing a json array with "result[x].variable", inside of a jQuery command, inside of an ajax call - what is the best way to do a "while" loop that puts the stuff into the div and "adjusts itself" for the correct number of lines.

And again, I thank you in advance for your help.

Edit: Here is the output with the "undefined".

undefined----133--------------Adams-------------John

----146--------------Alighieri-------------Beatrice

----154--------------Babb-------------Sh

----153--------------Belgian-------------Rosy

----160--------------Canton-------------Daniel

----162--------------Gallo-------------Bethel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var output = "";
$.each(result, function(index, value) {
    output += "----" + value.localid + "--------------" + value.lastname + "-------------" + value.firstname + "<br>";
});
```

To check if there is 15 or more results - `result.length >= 15`.

So final code will look like this:

```
$.ajax({//------------------------start of ajax---------------------------------->
    type: "POST",
    url: "findpatientbackend.php",
    data: {letterslastname: lastname},
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        if(result.length >= 15) {
            var output = "";
            $.each(result, function(index, value) {
                output += "----" + value.localid + "--------------" + value.lastname + "-------------" + value.firstname + "<br>";
            });
            $("#div1").html(output);
        }
    },
    error : function() { alert("error on return"); }
});
```

Comment: It works! It Works! IT WORKS! Thanks so VERY much! I'd seen that .each function before, but stayed away from it - now I can see how to use it in other areas.

Comment: There is one TINY little problem - the first line of each query gives back an "undefined". I'll edit my post above to add the output as an example - I'll play around a bit to see why it's there. Again THANKS very much!

Comment: My bad problem is in inicialzation, shoud be `var output = ""`

Comment: Absolutely superb! So setting the output to null ("") just sends a null character to the first line. Thanks so much again...I'll be spending some time on the .each command, and how you added a function within the .each command - that is very interesting. Thanks very much again!